# Total number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have a problem, I created a stored procedure which is a little complicated , this is the code :

```
SELECT TOP (25) 
    [Project1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], 
    [Project1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project1].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], 
    [Project1].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], 
    [Project1].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], 
    [Project1].[Libelle1] AS [Libelle1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], [Project1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], [Project1].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], [Project1].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], [Project1].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], [Project1].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], [Project1].[Libelle1] AS [Libelle1], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], 
            [Extent1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], 
            [Extent2].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], 
            [Extent4].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], 
            [Extent4].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], 
            [Extent5].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], 
            [Extent6].[Libelle] AS [Libelle1], 
            LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent1].[IDC_NOM])) AS [C1], 
            LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent2].[ICP_NMNAISS])) AS [C2], 
             CAST( [Extent2].[ICP_DTNAISS] AS datetime2) AS [C3], 
             CAST( [Extent3].[ICR_DTCREA_ENTREPRISE] AS datetime2) AS [C4], 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE  CAST( [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] AS nvarchar(max)) END AS [C5]
            FROM      [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT_PHYSIQUE] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent2].[ICP_IDCONTACT]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT_PROFESSIONNEL] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent3].[ICR_IDCONTACT]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[ADRESSE_CONTACT] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent4].[ADC_IDADR]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[Ref_Profil_Contact] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[IDC_CDPROFIL_CONTACT] = [Extent5].[Cod]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[Ref_Statut] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[IDC_CDSTATUTSOC] = [Extent6].[Cod]
            WHERE ( NOT ((9975 = [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE]) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT ((9976 = [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE]) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NOT NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPROFIL_CONTACT] = 'P')
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC'
```

I want to also return the total number of rows, not the only 25 rows, I don't know where to put `count(*)`. There is always an error. Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add in the select `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY) [Project1].[C1] ASC`

Comment: i add the count(*) in where you mention , but i gate an error :

Comment: the column Project1.IDC_IDCONTACT is not valid because is not in the aggregation function or in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: i'm trying to translate the error for you because i have sql in french :)

Comment: Dont add count add what I wrote above

Comment: sorry i dont understand you , i have yet this line of code in my stored procedure (in the second select) . can you modify the code and repost it . thx

Comment: `SELECT x,y,z,[row_number],y` in the exterior select,you already have the row_number in there

Comment: this will add a column in the result that contain value from 1 -> 25 because i return only the first 25 row , but what i want is to return the max value of [row_number] (not 25) .

Comment: for example the second select is returning 10000 row , what i'm doing right now is to select the first 25 row , i want also to return the value 10000

Comment: i don't know if you understand me , i'm not good in english sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
COUNT(1) OVER () AS records_count,
```

to your query.

For me it works fine:

```
SELECT [id]
  ,[p_value]
  ,COUNT(1) OVER () AS records_count
FROM [dbo].[tb_temp]
```

Returns:

[image]

And for TOP(N) case:

[image]

Optimized for performance query:

```
WITH QueryCTE AS 
(

  SELECT 
    [Project1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], 
    [Project1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project1].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], 
    [Project1].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], 
    [Project1].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], 
    [Project1].[Libelle1] AS [Libelle1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], [Project1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], [Project1].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], [Project1].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], [Project1].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], [Project1].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], [Project1].[Libelle1] AS [Libelle1], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], 
            [Extent1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], 
            [Extent2].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], 
            [Extent4].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], 
            [Extent4].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], 
            [Extent5].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], 
            [Extent6].[Libelle] AS [Libelle1], 
            LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent1].[IDC_NOM])) AS [C1], 
            LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent2].[ICP_NMNAISS])) AS [C2], 
             CAST( [Extent2].[ICP_DTNAISS] AS datetime2) AS [C3], 
             CAST( [Extent3].[ICR_DTCREA_ENTREPRISE] AS datetime2) AS [C4], 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE  CAST( [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] AS nvarchar(max)) END AS [C5]
            FROM      [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT_PHYSIQUE] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent2].[ICP_IDCONTACT]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT_PROFESSIONNEL] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent3].[ICR_IDCONTACT]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[ADRESSE_CONTACT] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent4].[ADC_IDADR]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[Ref_Profil_Contact] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[IDC_CDPROFIL_CONTACT] = [Extent5].[Cod]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[Ref_Statut] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[IDC_CDSTATUTSOC] = [Extent6].[Cod]
            WHERE ( NOT ((9975 = [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE]) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT ((9976 = [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE]) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NOT NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPROFIL_CONTACT] = 'P')
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
)

SELECT TOP (25) 
    *       
  FROM QueryCTE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(1) AS record_count FROM QueryCTE) cnt_qry
  ORDER BY [C1] ASC
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: yes it work but it become very slow . it make 53 second to return 811285 row :(

Comment: I've added optimized for performance version of query, please use it for better performance

Answer (score 0):

You can user CTE to help you in this case in order to user your query with and without the TOP clause.

Something like (Quite Ugly but should work) :

```
 WITH QueryCTE AS 
(
SELECT 
    [Project1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], 
    [Project1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project1].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], 
    [Project1].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], 
    [Project1].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], 
    [Project1].[Libelle1] AS [Libelle1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], [Project1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], [Project1].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], [Project1].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], [Project1].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], [Project1].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], [Project1].[Libelle1] AS [Libelle1], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], 
            [Extent1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], 
            [Extent2].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], 
            [Extent4].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], 
            [Extent4].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], 
            [Extent5].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], 
            [Extent6].[Libelle] AS [Libelle1], 
            LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent1].[IDC_NOM])) AS [C1], 
            LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent2].[ICP_NMNAISS])) AS [C2], 
             CAST( [Extent2].[ICP_DTNAISS] AS datetime2) AS [C3], 
             CAST( [Extent3].[ICR_DTCREA_ENTREPRISE] AS datetime2) AS [C4], 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE  CAST( [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] AS nvarchar(max)) END AS [C5]
            FROM      [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT_PHYSIQUE] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent2].[ICP_IDCONTACT]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT_PROFESSIONNEL] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent3].[ICR_IDCONTACT]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[ADRESSE_CONTACT] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent4].[ADC_IDADR]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[Ref_Profil_Contact] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[IDC_CDPROFIL_CONTACT] = [Extent5].[Cod]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[Ref_Statut] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[IDC_CDSTATUTSOC] = [Extent6].[Cod]
            WHERE ( NOT ((9975 = [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE]) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT ((9976 = [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE]) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NOT NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPROFIL_CONTACT] = 'P')
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0

)
SELECT TOP (25) 
* 
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueryCTE) AS NBRows
FROM QueryCTE
ORDER BY [C1] ASC
```